# FQL query to fetch all data of a facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to fetch all the accessible data of a facebook page (Only **page** table data is enough for me now). I only have the page url of that page. After observing some urls i found that the url's can be in the following 2 formats.

- http://www.facebook.com/**username**
- http://www.facebook.com/pages/**name/page_id**

Now what i am doing is querying in facebook **page** table by username(for 1st type of url's) or page_id(for 2nd one's).

Here are the questions..

- Am i doing anything wrong?
- Anyone have any better sugestion? actually i am searching for a generation solution of this problem.
- I also want to get the page visits count. Can you please give me some idea of how can i find the visits count?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can't get visit counts for user profiles.

Comment: take a look at [Facebook Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/)

Comment: @Lix Thanks. I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the columns to query from page see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

the FQL will look like for by ID:

`SELECT {columns} FROM page WHERE page_id=PAGEID`

and for by page name:

`SELECT {columns} FROM page WHERE username='PAGEUSERNAME'`

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can fetch data from a page querying by page_id/username. My question was the way i extract page_id/username from facebook page url is correct/work for all pages?

Comment: No, some will have a username and some will be by id.

Comment: How to fetch videos posted in that page .