# Can I access a Facebook Page with the Graph API without creating an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the past, I think a Facebook Page access token could be generated manually, and then used with the graph API to query posts, comments, likes, shares, etc. Now it seems you cannot query anything without developing an app that I login to and then in turn the app generates the access token. Is that true? For example, [this question from 2015 claims no access token is needed for public data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072253/retrieve-data-of-a-facebook-page-with-graph-api), but when I try their example it returns "An access token is required to request this resource."

I'm the admin of my page that ran a basic contest (giveaway). I'd like to use the graph API to fetch the names of people that liked, shared, or commented on a post. Then I want to cross reference it with those that like the page. Do I have to register and develop an app for this? Does my page have an access token available without going through the app registration and review process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access a Facebook Page with the Graph API without creating an app?

No, that is not possible. You always have to use an App for any API Access.

> Then I want to cross reference it with those that like the page.

That is not possible either, not even with an App. I assume you want to make sure that participants like your Page - which is not allowed. People cannot be "incentivized" to like your Page.

Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Explanation about the specific rule against requiring people to like your Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: The policy on [Promotions on Pages, Groups, and Events](https://www.facebook.com/policies/pages_groups_events/) only says you cannot require the user to post on their timeline or a friend's. I actually cannot recall a contest promoted on Facebook that didn't say liking the page was a requirement for entry.

Comment: Thank you for confirming an app is required for any graph access now. I'll review the other policies as well.

Comment: 4.5: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions."

Comment: i have added some more information to the answer. in the examples page it´s very clear that it is not allowed to require a page like.

Comment: I believe the difference is the policy allows it for a business page running a contest, but not for an app trying to boost its own likes.

Comment: there is no difference, it´s about pages and page likes and the rules are pretty clear about that. it was allowed several years ago, but not anymore.